# Create a JDBC connection to HBase

Tags: hbase, cdata-drivers

I am trying to cretae a JDBC to connection to HBase in our cluster using CDATA (https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/hbase-jdbc-dbvr.rst)

The HBase properties in our cluster is as follow:

```
hbase.zookeeper.quorum=auper01-01-20-01-0.prod.vroc.com.au,auper01-02-10-01-0.prod.vroc.com.au,auper01-02-10-02-0.prod.vroc.com.au
hbase.zookeeper.port=2181
hbase.zokeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-unsecure
```

Based on the document, i have set the JDBC URL as follow:

```
jdbc:apachehbase:Server=auper01-01-20-01-0.prod.vroc.com.au,auper01-02-10-01-0.prod.vroc.com.au,auper01-02-10-02-0.prod.vroc.com.au;Port=2181;
```

but it doesn't fetch data from HBase database..Does anyone know how to populate the JDBC string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the wrong value for the `Server` property. In your connection string, set the `Server` property in the connection to the IP address or hostname of the **HBase master**, not the `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` property value. For example:

```
jdbc:apachehbase:Server=###.###.###.###;Port=2181;
```